# Google cloud sql not connected with my project(Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

**LoginAuthServlet.java**

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
            String url="jdbc:google:mysql://Instance_connection_name/dbname?user=xyz&password=abc";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            String query = "SELECT  "
                        + "  * "
                        + " FROM "
                        + "  users "
                        + " WHERE "
                        + "   user_username = ? AND user_password = ? AND user_status = '1' "
                        /*+ "     user_type = ? "*/
                        + " limit 0,1";
                PreparedStatement stmtLogin = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                stmtLogin.setString(1, username);
                stmtLogin.setString(2, userPassword);

                ResultSet resource = stmtLogin.executeQuery();
                if(resource.next()){
                        HttpSession sess = req.getSession();
                        sess.setAttribute("isLogin", "true");

                        sess.setAttribute("userId", resource.getString("user_id"));
                        sess.setAttribute("userName", resource.getString("user_username"));
                        sess.setAttribute("userType", resource.getString("user_type"));
                        sess.setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60);
                        resp.sendRedirect("BusinessList.jsp"); 
                    }
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
 <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
```

When i deploy this project and attempt to login then give response is {}.....
i included all the jar file and if i am try to connect locally with IPV4 address then it work well,but if i deploy project then it's not work,i done all the things but my project can't connect with google cloud sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a second generation instance, in order to connect from appengine you also need to include the region JDBC url like below:

```
String url="jdbc:google:mysql://[PROJECT-ID]:[REGION]:[INSTANCE-NAME]/dbname?user=xyz&password=abc";
```

Here they provide some example:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/